# How to store Url into ArrayList from Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I am trying to get list of all Url from Firebase Storage into ArrayList. I tried using getDownloadUrl() method but ArrayList remains empty.

Here is my code-

```
public class LoggedIn extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
    
    ArrayList<Uri> Url=new ArrayList<>();
StorageReference storageReference= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    int in;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_logged_in);
        Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        String value = extras.getString("email");

        for(in=1;in<6;in++){
            storageReference.child(in+".png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                    Url.add(in,uri);
                    Log.d("success",String.valueOf(uri));

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Failed",String.valueOf(e));
                }
            });


        }
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you're using the `Url` list before `Url.add(in,uri)` has executed.

Since `getDownloadUrl()` requires a call to the server, it is handled asynchronously. This means that your main code continues to run, while the app waits for the download URL in the background. Then once the download URL is available, your `onSuccess` is called with that value.

I'll link some similar problems below, but the important thing to remember is that any code that needs the download URL, needs to be inside the `onSuccess` or be called from there.

If you want to wait for all download URLs to be available, you can use [`Tasks.whenAllSuccess`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAllSuccess(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E...)).

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[6];
for(in=1;in<6;in++){
    Task task = storageReference.child(in+".png").getDownloadUrl();
    tasks[i] = task;
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            Url.add(in,uri);
            Log.d("success",String.valueOf(uri));
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d("Failed",String.valueOf(e));
        }
    });
}
Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Uri> results) {
        ... you can use `resuls` or `Url` here
    }
})
```

See also:

- [How to get download url for firebase storage and update firestore document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62699565/how-to-get-download-url-for-firebase-storage-and-update-firestore-document/62699990#62699990)
- [Can someone help me with logic of the firebase on success listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039870/can-someone-help-me-with-logic-of-the-firebase-on-success-listener/57040546#57040546)
- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener/33204705#33204705)
- [Firebase - Android - fetchProvidersForEmail - Why are all the calls asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918459/firebase-android-fetchprovidersforemail-why-are-all-the-calls-asynchronous/41918701#41918701)
- [How to deal with the values taken from asynchronous methods like onComplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60805694/how-to-deal-with-the-values-taken-from-asynchronous-methods-like-oncomplete/60806278#60806278)