# firebase Storage return null

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

real i'm not sure if can explain the proplem

1-I need to get posts from realtime_firebase
2-every post has a user_id

then I need to get user Image from Storage_firebase  by userId

the problem is return null for image

Code

```
fun getPosts(liveData: MutableLiveData<List<Post>>) {
        val databaseRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Posts")
        var posts: ArrayList<Post> = ArrayList()
        databaseRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                posts.clear()
                for (snapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    var post = snapshot.getValue(Post::class.java)
                    post?.image = getUserImage(post?.userId!!)
                    posts.add(post!!)
                }
                liveData.value = posts
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
    }
private fun getUserImage(user_id: String): String? {
    var imageUri = ""
    firebaseStorage.reference.child("users").child("profile")
        .child(user_id).downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
      //problem is not access to this methode
            imageUri = it.toString()
        }
    return imageUri
}
```

Comment: So you say that `firebaseStorage` object is null? Did you initialize it? If yes, show us where did you do that.

Comment: In that case, firebaseStorage isn't null, right? It's about the `imageUri` being null, correct?

Comment: I'am using dagger hilt to initialize

 Provides
    Singleton
    fun getStorage(): FirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()

and it run when upload Image 
problem is not access to addOnSuccessListener

Comment: yes firebaseStorage is Not null 

put  problem not access to addOnSuccessListener

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. So which object is null?

Comment: it's not access to this methode 
 firebaseStorage.reference.child("users").child("profile")
        .child(user_id).downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
      //problem is not access to this methode
            imageUri = it.toString()
        }

Comment: What do you mean by ""problem is not access to this methode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my function that calls an API return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Answer (score 1):

I'm solving the problem but not understand why
-using MutableStateFlow to return value

```
 databaseRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                posts.clear()
                for (snapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    var post = snapshot.getValue(Post::class.java)
                    GlobalScope.launch {
                        getUserImage(post?.userId!!).collect {
                            post?.image = it
                        }
                    }

                    posts.add(post!!)
                }
                liveData.value = posts
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
    }

    private fun getUserImage(user_id: String): MutableStateFlow<String> {
        var imageUri = MutableStateFlow<String>("")

        var imageRef = firebaseStorage.reference.child("users").child("profile")
            .child(user_id).downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
            GlobalScope.launch {
                imageUri.emit(it.toString())
            }
        }

        return imageUri
    }
```

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm using MutableStateFlow to solve

Comment: Good to see you got it working @medmjs. To understand why your original return didn't work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68179709/how-to-store-url-into-arraylist-from-firebase-storage/68180018#68180018

Comment: Thank you a lot